# How do I create a datatable in Autodesk Forge?

Tags: node.js, autodesk-forge

As shown in the following figure, I would like to create a data table with attribute information about the model uploaded to Autodesk Forge as shown in the figure below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaLw2.jpg)

The Autodesk Forge I implemented is
It was written with reference to **https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/tutorials/dashboard.**

And I tried to write the data table by referring to **https://forge-tutorials.autodesk.io/tutorials/dashboard/grid/**, but 'Uncaught (in promise) Extension not found: LoggerExtension.' An error like this occurred.

```
Through the Autodesk Forge example I implemented
public/js/ForgeViewer.js
Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, () => {
    viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(document.getElementById('forgeViewer'), { extensions: ['HandleSelectionExtension','ModelSummaryExtension','LoggerExtension'] });
    viewer.start();
    var documentId = 'urn:' + urn;
    Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(documentId, onDocumentLoadSuccess, onDocumentLoadFailure);
  });
```

I added LoggerExtension in extensions as shown, but it is not implemented.

`import './extensions/LoggerExtension.js'`; was used by changing

```
<script type="module" src="extensions/LoggerExtension.js"></script> in index.html.
```

I want to implement a data table using ForgeViewer.js in my Autodesk Forge implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because the LoggerExtension is not registered.

The extension needs to be registered under a specific unique ID so that the viewer can find it. This is all stated in the Forge tutorials: https://forge-tutorials.autodesk.io/tutorials/dashboard/basic#simple-extension

What you therefore need to do is register the LoggerExtension using the singleton object `Autodesk.Viewing.theExtensionManager.registerExtension('LoggerExtension', LoggerExtension);`

This object is placed at the bottom of the LoggerExtension.js file.

This should enable the viewer to recognize it!

Comment: I solved it. Thanks for your advice.
As a workaround, I had to add an extension like this: 
in index.html 
 <script type="module" src="js/LoggerExtension.js"></script>
  <script type="module" src="js/SummaryExtension.js"></script>
  <script type="module" src="js/DataGridExtension.js"></script>

in ForgeViewer.js
viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(document.getElementById('forgeViewer'), { extensions: ['LoggerExtension','SummaryExtension', 'DataGridExtension'] });

Thank you